# To the LCMS Lutherans, how is the Bible the word of God?

Tags: bible, lutheranism, inspiration, protestant-bible

A. The Bible is the Word of God. 
(means, all the words we read are the Words of God)

B. The Bible contains the Word of God. 
(means, not all the words we read are the Words of God)

C. other than A and B.

---

Example :

> I decided that while I was with you I would forget everything except
>   Jesus Christ, the one who was crucified

The speaker is human, the Apostle. 
The question is : *are those words above the words of God ?*

To me, the answer is no. Those words are the words of human not the words of God.

If I say that those words are the words of God, --->

then (X) the "I" in those words means God himself ---->

Then (Y) it become : *through the mouth of the Apostle, God tell the hearers/readers that He (capital H) decided while He was with them, He would forget everything except His Second Person of His Trinity, the one who was crucified.*

Because X and Y to me feel awkward, I conclude [not all the words we read in the Bible are the Words of God]. Then it's B. But this is only my own logic.

That's why I would like to know : 
*according to the LCMS is it A ? B ? or C?

If C, what is it ?*

Thank you.

Comment: You would be better served by asking for an overview of US Lutheran denominations rather than asking so many questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii, as my post before - I put a link from what I think is Lutheran where in this link it seems they/he/she holds A. Because I thought it's Lutheran (whatever denomination) that's why I ask how is (for example) 1 Corinthians 2:2 are the words of God. But then somebody commented that the link is a personal opinion not from Lutheran. That's why now I check "one by one" to find which Lutheran denomination who holds A. That's why so many question, because I don't know which Lutheran denomination who holds A, curiousdannii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View A reflects the [LCMS view](https://www.lcms.org/about/beliefs/doctrine/statement-of-scriptural-and-confessional-principles#IV).

> We believe, teach and confess that all Scripture is given by the inspiration of God the Holy Spirit and that **God is therefore the true Author of every word of Scripture**.  [Emphasis mine]

Concerning the use of the personal pronoun 'l', this may be on point:

> We therefore reject the following views:
>   ...
>   That the Holy Spirit did not inspire the actual words of the Biblical authors but merely provid­ed these men with special guidance....

Further, the LCMS acknowledges that this position is not explicitly stated in the Book of Concord, but believes it to be the correct, historical Lutheran position:

> We recognize that the Lutheran Confessions contain no distinct article on the nature of Holy Scripture and its interpretation, but we acknowledge and accept the confessional understanding of the nature of Holy Scripture and of the proper theological principles for its interpretation.

Comment: There is a particular quotation on interpreting Scripture that I want to add, but I can't find it at the moment. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I agree with you that this view **[God is therefore the true Author of every word of Scripture]** reflects A. So now I can continue to make a new question based on this view about (for example) 1 Corinthians 2:2. Thank you bradimus.